# Who can tell me the last parameter of Windows API method SendMessage represent?

Tags: c++, c

Eg.

SendMessage(hwnd,WM_KEYDOWN,VK_DELETE,1)

To set the last parameter 1,what's mean?what's the difference when set it NULL or any other number?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Comment: @EJP yeah. LPARAM:a additional message

Comment: Have you also looked at the documentation for what those parameters mean for [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: 32bit  of LPARAM？

Comment: [RTFM here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

By [mdsn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx), the last lParam stores:

> The repeat count, scan code, extended-key flag, context code, previous key-state flag, and transition-state flag, as shown following.
>
> Bits (0-15)   Meaning:
>
> The repeat count for the current message. The value is the number of times the keystroke is autorepeated as a result of the user holding down the key. If the keystroke is held long enough, multiple messages are sent. However, the repeat count is not cumulative.

Comment: I know that ，but I can't understand the  last  parameter of SendMessage  1

Comment: @konalo what is the problem? You send a 1 meaning the current message has a repeat count of 1.

Comment: @konalo: You need to look up the documentation for a specific messages (`WM_KEYDOWN` in your case) to learn what the meaning of the parameters passed when sending it (via `SendMessage()` for example) would mean.